# Bootstrap 4 - The Carousel automatically zooms into a part of the image to make it fit is there a way to change that?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

It zooms into one area in the image is it possible to change where it zooms into?

Yes, I do know having the correct resolution would be better but I don't know the optimum resolution for the carousel.

Here is the link to the fiddle thing so you can see.
https://jsfiddle.net/rmbeo4oh/

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="wpimages/received_10214620274008052.jpeg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean _"It zooms into one area in the image"_? Could you elaborate a bit more? Are you talking about the image being 100% width and becoming larger?

Comment: @zgood Since the carousel isn't big enough it zooms into the image to fit the carousel window on certain resolutions.

Comment: remove `w-100` and the images won't stretch to fill the screen then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to use something like Photoshop to cut the assets according to your needs, but if that's not an option you can use a CSS transform.

I'm assuming you're just interested in adjusting the vertical alignment since the images in the carousel are set to 100% width. Either create some helper classes (i.e. `.pull-20`) or add descriptive class names (i.e. `.security-camera`) to the images and adjust accordingly:

```
<img class="d-block w-100 security-camera" src="wpimages/received_10214620274008052.jpeg" alt="First slide">

.security-camera {
    transform: translateY(-20%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rmbeo4oh/1/